# Values not getting binded from jsp to action class in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am working on Struts2 web application and currently i am facing issue with the form binding. The binding from jsp to the action class is not working.

The scenario is i am having a list which is being set from the previous action. In current jsp I am iterating over the list and printing the values in the Table in jsp. Due to a requirement i am supposed to make the fields editable so that user can edit the values displayed and submit the updated values to the next action.

The problem is that the values that i edit from the jsp are not being bound to the list in action class. I have tried multiple ways but no luck till now. below are the ways that i have tried.

The First way i tried values are not getting bound:

```xml
<s:iterator value="list1" var="sVO" status="rowStatus">
    <tr onclick="SelIndex('<s:property value="itm_id"/>');">
        <td><s:property value="itm_id"/></td>
        <td><s:date name="proc_d" format="MM/dd/YYYY"/></td>
        <td><span style="display:none;"><s:property value="pln_n_n"/></span><input type="text" size = "8" value="<s:property value="pln_n_n"/>"/></td>
        <td><span style="display:none;"><s:date name="trd_d" format="MM/dd/YYYY"/></span><input type="text" size = "8" class="dateFilter" value="<s:date name="trd_d" format="MM/dd/YYYY"/>"/></td>
        <td><s:select theme="simple" name="list1[%{rowStatus.index}].vari_ty" id="tranType" list="liTTypes" headerKey="None" value="vari_ty" listKey="key1" listValue="value1" /></td>
        <td><span style="display:none;"><s:property value="description"/></span><input type="text" size = "8" value="<s:property value="description"/>"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="getText('format.money',{quantity})"/></td>
        <td><span style="display:none;"><s:property value="getText('format.money',{price})"/></span><input type="text" size = "10"  value="<s:property value="getText('format.money',{price})"/>"/></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator
```

The second way i tried values not getting bound:

```xml
<s:iterator value="list1" var="sVO" status="rowStatus">
    <tr onclick="SelIndex('<s:property value="itm_id"/>');">
        <td><s:property value="itm_id"/></td>
        <td><s:date name="proc_d" format="MM/dd/YYYY"/></td>
        <td><span style="display:none;"><s:property value="pln_n_n"/></span>
            <input type="text" name="list1[%{#rowStatus.index}].pln_n_n" value="<s:property value="pln_n_n"/>"/></td>
        <td><span style="display:none;"><s:date name="trd_d" format="MM/dd/YYYY"/></span>
            <input type="text" size = "8" name="list1[%{#rowStatus.index}].trd_d" class="dateFilter" value="<s:date name="trd_d" format="MM/dd/YYYY"/>"/></td>
        <td><s:select theme="simple" name="list1[%{rowStatus.index}].vari_ty" id="tranType" list="liTTypes" headerKey="None" value="vari_ty" listKey="key1" listValue="value1" /></td>
        <td><span style="display:none;"><s:property value="description"/></span>
            <input type="text" name="list1[%{#rowStatus.index}].description" size = "8" value="<s:property value="description"/>"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="getText('format.money',{quantity})"/></td>
        <td><span style="display:none;"><s:property value="getText('format.money',{price})"/></span>
            <input type="text" name="list1[%{#rowStatus.index}].price" size = "10"  value="<s:property value="getText('format.money',{price})"/>"/></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Below is the action class that i have

```
 public class testAction extends BaseAction 
    {

private List<ProcessVO> list1 = null;
   // getters and setters for list1 


   public String ListPage() throws AppException
     {
        String strReturn = "SUCCESS";           
    // This the method from which the list1 is populated   }

   public String ListPageSave() throws AppException
    {
        String strReturn = "SUCCESS";

    // This the method where i need the updated values from list1
    // values are not getting bound when this method is called from the page which is having Iterator tag,
     }
```

}

```
  BaseAction:

   public class BaseAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware, ServletContextAware {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * HTTP Request object.
```

}
The `ProcessVO` contains the attributes and getters and setters for each attribute.

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here. I am using the same list1 object which needs to be updated. Any help will be very useful for me as i am stuck with this issue.

Comment: What is `AppBaseAction`? Post the code.

Comment: BaseAction is just a class that extends Action support and implements interfaces. Modified the code as above

Comment: Why do you implement interfaces on the base class?

Comment: @Roman its just a library that i am using in my code.

Comment: What library, I didn't get what you saying?

Comment: @Roman by library means its written specifically for our project. It contains code for setting session,request attributes in session, request etc.Its kind of a wrapper. i am not sure is that the problem.

Comment: Are you sure about what is the problem?

Comment: No Sir that is the reason i have posted my query. perhaps you could help me. i feel that there is a issue while binding values which is causing the problem. but i need your advice on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107319/discussion-between-roman-c-and-vikeng21).

Comment: @Roman i cannot access chat on my system. Can we please continue here itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```xml
> <input type = "text" 
>        name = "list1[%{#rowStatus.index}].pln_n_n" 
>       value = "<s:property value="pln_n_n"/>"/>
> ```

If you use HTML tags, OGNL won't work inside them.

You need to either use `<s:property/>`:

```xml
<input type = "text" 
       name = "list1[<s:property value="%{#rowStatus.index}"/>].pln_n_n" 
      value = "<s:property value="pln_n_n"/>"/>
```

or use Struts2 Tags, where OGNL works:

```xml
<s:textfield name = "list1[%{#rowStatus.index}].pln_n_n"
            value = "pln_n_n" />
```

---

Side notes:

1. `value` is not needed if it's *not* different from `name`, and
2. `"SUCCESS"` is against the convention, it should be `"success"` (mapped by the `SUCCESS` constant)

Comment: you are awesome. Thank you so much for your help. Its working fine and values are getting mapped from jsp to action correctly :)

Comment: sorry i forgot to upvote your answer. i have done it now. thanks a lot once again.